# Check pre-conditions and post-conditions

Tags: liquibase

I see that liquibase has [preconditions](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/preconditions.html), but I would also like to validate the changeset after it's been applied.

The specific use case is checking it didn't create more invalid objects in the DB,

e.g. in Oracle

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM USER_OBJECTS O
WHERE O.STATUS = 'INVALID';
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There’s no such built-in thing as postConditions in Liquibase.

But you can always use `sqlCheck` preCondition as a workaround, e.g.:

```
<changeSet id=“foo” author=“bar”>
    <!—- do some changes you need —->
</changeSet>

<changeSet id=“foo1” author=“bar”>
    <preConditions onFail=“ERROR”>
        <sqlCheck expextedResult=“1”>
            SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM USER_OBJECTS O
            WHERE O.STATUS = 'INVALID';
        </sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>Result from changeSet “foo” verified successfully</comment>
</changeSet>
```